# How to convert Date Time parameter to UTC in Generic Inquiry

Tags: acumatica

If you have some date time parameter in generic inquiry to use it in where clause, it will be sent to the sql query in local time zone. Does anybody know how to convert it to UTC date time? I need this because date time fields are stored in UTC in Acumatica database.

The easy example is GI to show events in the specified date time span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert date time parameter into UTC, one can use  `-Now()+NowUTC()` functions.
Here is an example [image: EventByDatesGenericInquiry]